# What’s the purpose of the HTML “nomodule” attribute for script elements if the default is text/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am not clearly understanding why the `nomodule` attribute exists in the new browsers that support ES6 modules.

In HTML 5, the `type` attribute is optional and [defaults to `text/javascript`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#script):

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

It doesn't default to `<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>`. Has this default changed? If not, why would `nomodule` be necessary? Can I just use `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` without `nomodule`?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The [purpose of the `nomodule` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-nomodule) is to cause newer browsers that support [module scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) to ignore a particular `script` element:

> The `nomodule` attribute is a boolean attribute that prevents a script from being executed in user agents that support module scripts.

The spec [has a good example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-nomodule-example):

> This example shows how to include a module script for modern user agents, and a classic script for older user agents:

> ```
> <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
> <script nomodule src="classic-app-bundle.js"></script>
> ```
>
> In modern user agents that support module scripts, the `script` element with the `nomodule` attribute will be ignored, and the `script` element with a type of "`module`" will be fetched and evaluated (as a module script). Conversely, older user agents will ignore the `script` element with a type of "`module`", as that is an unknown script type for them — but they will have no problem fetching and evaluating the other `script` element (as a classic script), since they do not implement the `nomodule` attribute.

So that’s how it works.

> In HTML 5, the `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text/javascript`… Has this default changed?

The default hasn’t changed—it’s still `text/javascript`. But the `type` attribute can now also have the value `module`, which means browsers still parse and execute it as `text/javascript`—but also specifically as a [module script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script).

> If not, why would `nomodule` be necessary?

It’s needed in order to prevent new browsers that support module scripts from executing scripts intended only for old browsers that don’t support module scripts, as in the above example.

> Can I just use `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` without `nomodule`?

Yes, if `bundle.js` doesn’t use modules. If it uses modules, you want to put `type=module` on it (in which case old browsers ignore it since they don’t recognize the `module` value for `type`).

Comment: So does it mean it would always be best to have 2 script? One for new browser, and one for older ones?

Comment: @IrfandyJip Where you use new features, yes. It helps you optimise for newer browsers since they don't have to handle a lot of code that is only there for compatibility with old browsers. Angular 8 does this and calls it "differential loading". In one of the projects I'm working on, it allowed us to cut code size for modern browsers almost in half.

Comment: Which browsers (with a market share  > 1%) will use the old (nomodule) way?

Answer (score 12):

### nomodule attribute

The nomodule attribute is a boolean attribute which is used to indicate to a browser **which does** support modules that a certain script tag **doesn't need to be loaded**.

The purpose of the nomodule attribute is to have a **backup script** for older browser who don't support the `<script type="module">` and thus will ignore them. Because the older browser neither support the `<script type="module">` nor the nomodule attribute the following scenarios can occur:

---

**Newer browsers**, supports `<script type="module">` &  `<script nomodule  type="text/javascript">`

- The browser can load and execute the `<script type="module">` script
- The browser recognizes the nomodule attribute and doesn't load `<script nomodule  type="text/javascript">`.

---

**Older browsers**, **don't** support `<script type="module">` &  `<script nomodule  type="text/javascript">`

- The browser will ignore the `<script type="module">` since its implementation cannot process this. No script will be downloaded and executed.
- The browser will ignore the nomodule attribute since and will continue to dowload and execute the  `<script nomodule  type="text/javascript">` script.

Answer (score 3):

## nomodule attribute

> **As other answers mentioned, This Boolean attribute is set to indicate**
> **that the script should not be executed in browsers that support ES2015**
> **modules — in effect, this can be used to serve fallback scripts to**
> **older browsers that do not support modular JavaScript code.**

Now let's understand with an example.

I'm using ES6/ES2015 features and need to include core.js to run application in IE browser and other major browser like Chrome, Firefox, Safari are supporting ES6/ES2015 features. You can see total vender size will be 150 kB for IE browser.

```html
<script src="core.js"></script> // Around 45 kB after gzip
<script src="obserPoly.js"></script> // Around 5 kB after gzip
<script src="vender.js"></script> // Around 100 kB after gzip
```

---

Why should I load core.js & obserpoly.js (45 kB + 5 kB = 50 kB) in other browsers. I have used nomodule attribute with my script and it worked like a champ. Now, Core.js and obserPoly.js scripts load in IE browsers only.

```html
<script nomodule src="core.js"></script> // Around 45 kB after gzip
<script nomodule src="obserPoly.js"></script> // Around 5 kB after gzip
<script src="vender.js"></script> // Around 100 kB after gzip
```